# How to left-shift numbers greater than 32-bits?

Tags: javascript, operators, bit-shift

As I understand it, JS treats numbers as 32-bits when performing bit-shift operations, even though it supports 64-bit numbers.

How can I implement a `leftShift` function that works on 64-bit numbers? i.e., it won't roll over into the negatives for something like `192 << 24` (should be `3221225472`, not `-1073741824`).

Comment: Javascript numbers are 64-bit floating point, they only have 53 bits of mantissa. So there's no way to get 64-bit integers.

Comment: @Barmar That's OK. I just need 32 unsigned bits. 53 is plenty :D

Comment: Use `192<<24>>>0` as shown in the question I linked to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do what the math of a [left shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) does:

> Arithmetic shifts are equivalent to multiplication by a positive (to the left) or by a negative number (to the right), integral power of the radix (e.g. a multiplication by a power of 2 for binary numbers).

```
function shift(number, shift) {
    return number * Math.pow(2, shift);
}

shift(192, 24)
//3221225472

shift(3221225472, -24)
//192
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was that simple, but I wasn't sure if I missing something.

Comment: You should add a Math.floor() because of rounding errors. For example `0xFFFFFFFF * Math.pow(2, -24) = 255.99999994039536` instead of 255.